# Pimcore CSV upload from folder location and create data objects automatically

Tags: pimcore

I'm trying to import csv from pimcore /web/var/temp folder and want to create data objects automatically.

Not using admin interface I need to do this using code.

Is there any example or solution to follow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to this it can done using https://github.com/w-vision/ImportDefinitions

It can import CSV and it'll automatically create data-object as well.

we can run import process using command line, we can configure crone job to run command.

Thanks